# How can I use PHP to set my navbar hrefs to absolute paths?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, href

I need to set these anchor href tags to absolute paths because when I have html docs in folders, the header where I include a lot of stuff doesn't work (need ../ in some cases).

I have looked at a few posts that have suggested using:

`$root = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

or

`$root = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`

The first option resulted in an error:

> localhost/:1 Not allowed to load local resource: `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/trips/index.php%7D`

The second option resulted in this error:

> Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\MountainPlanner\includes\header.php on line 17
>
> Warning: include(http://localhost/MountainPlanner/includes/db.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\MountainPlanner\includes\header.php on line 17
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'http://localhost/MountainPlanner/includes/db.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\MountainPlanner\includes\header.php on line 17

I am using XAMPP if that makes a difference.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't rely on $_SERVER for includes.   Use the `__DIR__`  constant and append the proper relative path from the directory the current file is in.

Comment: Your question is confusing because your asking about hrefs but your error deals with PHP includes.  It seems like you have more than one issue at hand here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HREF navbar path != System Path

**URL path**

It's what you see in your browser address, it's used by HTML (CSS, JavaScript, etc...). PHP don't need to worry about it (except by some streams functions).

To create the base path dynamically, I've used this script

```
httpProtocol = !isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on' ? 'http' : 'https';

$base = $httpProtocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
```

And, when put in the `href` `a` tag:

```
<a href="<?php echo $base; ?>link" title="Link">Link</a>
```

**System Path**

It's what the server use to find any file on the server. PHP uses it to `include`/`require` any file located on the server or a shared one. Streams functions could use system path too and URL as well.

As I can see, you're asking about system path. I've used this code to normalize the application path:

```
ini_set('include_path',
    implode(
        PATH_SEPARATOR, 
        array_merge(
            array(dirname(__FILE__)),
            explode(PATH_SEPARATOR , ini_get('include_path'))
        ) 
    )
);
```

Then, my application root could be used as a absolute path only for my application:

```
/Application/Require.php
/Application/Script.php
index.php
```

It'll work on any file as well:

```
require('Application/Require.php');
require('Application/Script.php');
```

Comment: This is what fixed my issue thank you very much! I also decided to change the include path in PHP which is simplifying the problem at large for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the first line somewhere in your config or constants file or even 1st line in your file.

```
<?php $base_url = "http://localhost/mysite/"; ?>
```

Then you can create href links like this:

```
<a href="<?=base_url?>my-link">clickie</a>
```

Comment: Judging by the error, the OP is using PHP includes.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER contains the headers filled by the web server.  It is not reliable and it disables your code from being run in local or testing environments.  From php.net:

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here. That said, a large number of these variables are accounted for in the » CGI/1.1 specification, so you should be able to expect those.

In summary, do not rely on this to provide information about your server.

PHP provides magic constants `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` that gives you the full path to the file or directory of the current file.

For PHP includes, you should use these constants with the relative path to the file you wish to access.

For example:

```
include __DIR__ . '/../file_in_previous_directory.php';
include __DIR__ . '/file_in_same_directory.php';
```